# Recovering data from a disk with broken file system and reading errors

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

I have a Seagate laptop disk that I need to recover some data from it (photos), the problem is that I have some error reading problems (bad sectors). I've tried running `testdisk` with a quick search, it finds the partitions (2 of them) but the one that contains the data it says that `broken filesystem or no files`.

Is it worth it to do a deeper search? I am asking because with the broken sectors it is going to take la 3 days to do it (200gb)

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Linux command-line fu is strong, try using `ddrescue` to make a backup image of your hard disk, then use `foremost` to extract the photos (JPGs, I assume?)

From experience, I can say that this is a remarkably effective approach to use on failing drives if your objective is to recover the types of files that Foremost can recognise, including photos, movies, music, and Office documents.

`ddrescue` is special because it was designed specifically to read flaky disks. Regular `dd` will stop dead when it encounters errors; `ddrescue` shrugs, marks the bad sector to be tried again later, and moves on.

> GNU ddrescue is a data recovery tool. It copies data from one file or block device (hard disc, cdrom, etc) to another, trying hard to rescue data in case of read errors.

`foremost` is special because it does not rely on the filesystem at all. Your partition table or filesystem structures could be completely trashed, yet `foremost` will still recover (many of) your files.

> Foremost is a console program to recover files based on their headers, footers, and internal data structures. This process is commonly referred to as data carving. Foremost can work on image files, such as those generated by dd, Safeback, Encase, etc, or directly on a drive. The headers and footers can be specified by a configuration file or you can use command line switches to specify built-in file types. These built-in types look at the data structures of a given file format allowing for a more reliable and faster recovery.

Other alternatives are `PhotoRec` which runs on Windows, though I'm not sure how well it will do in the face of disk errors, and `GetDataBack` which is paid software.

Comment: I had never heard of `foresmost` before, I will give it a try. I had tried `ddrescue` but it had failed, don't know why. I will try it again

Comment: @w0rldart Just remember `dd_rescue` != `ddrescue`. Try using both, with various options, to recover as much as possible. It doesn't have to be (and is unlikely to be) a 100% correct image, but 99% of it should be good.

Comment: interesting, I thought they're both the same... I will do a research and see what info I can find. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a while ago and I can recommend hdd regenerator. Hdd regenerator claims to physically regenerate the bad sectors before you try to rescue it with programs like testdisk. There are a couple of hdd regenerator programs. I would give it a try. Maybe you can make a backup of your hard disk with dd before using hdd regenerator. Spinrite looks also promising: http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums//lofiversion/index.php/t19129.html.

[Then there is Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm), the original HDD sector recovery software, more expensive but they are offering a free upgrade to the newer version which is being released sometime in 2012.

Comment: tnx for the info, I'll give it a try to the hdd regenerator... I've tried `dd_rescue` but it blocked after a while, I will try it again

Comment: @w0rldart: Spinrite looks also promising. IMO good advertising.

Comment: @w0rldart: have you tried `ddrescue`? (Note: unrelated to `dd_rescue` apart from the name.)

Comment: HDD regen, Spinrite fall into same category: snake-oil.